# UITableView content of a row loads after scrolling the cell out of the view

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode, uitableview

the problem is, that the content of the cell loads after i scrolled the cell out of the view:
i dont know how to describe it correctly, so i recorded a short 10 seconds video: http://youtu.be/GJouA3IXY0M

and i dont know how to fix it...

this is my cellForRowAtIndexPath method:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    PlaylistenTableViewCell *cell = [self.playlistenTableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"Cell"];
    cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;

    //titleLabel = label which shows the big headline
    cell.titleLabel.text = [self.JsonTitle objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    cell.titleLabel.layer.cornerRadius = 5;
    cell.titleLabel.layer.masksToBounds = YES;


    NSString *urlString = [self.JsonContent objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlString];

    NSData *data = [[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:url];
    UIImage *tmpImage = [[UIImage alloc] initWithData:data];


    //playlistThumbnailImageView = the imageVIew which shows the Image
    cell.playlistThumbnailImageView.image = tmpImage;
    [cell.playlistThumbnailImageView setOpaque:NO];
    [cell.playlistThumbnailImageView setBackgroundColor:color];
    cell.playlistThumbnailImageView.layer.cornerRadius = 5;
    cell.playlistThumbnailImageView.layer.masksToBounds = YES;
    cell.playlistThumbnailImageView.layer.borderWidth = 4.0;


    return cell;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are most probably reloading the table with background thread. Make UI updates with main thread. So, after your data is fetched in the background, use this code.

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        [self.myTableView reloadData];
    });
```

Edit:

Since you have already reloading the table using main thread, I suspect that image is taking time to download and in turn it is blocking the thread. I also observed some glitch happening in your video. Try to download the image using asynchronous methods and check. `initWithContentsOfURL` will block your thread and is not a good option in this place.

Comment: hmmm, i added this to my code, but nothing chances. Still the same problem :/

Comment: Edited my answer. Just check.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code. Let me know in case of any query...

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    -------
    -------

    NSString *imageUrl = @"-- URL string --";

    NSURL *urlImage = [NSURL URLWithString:imageUrl];
    [imgVw setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"placeholder.png"]];

    dispatch_queue_t queue = dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_BACKGROUND, 0);
    dispatch_async(queue, ^{
        NSError* error = nil;
        NSData *imageData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:urlImage options:nil error:&error];

        if(error){
            dispatch_sync(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                [imgVw setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"placeholder.png"]];
                [self.loadingIndicator stopAnimating];
                [[NSURLCache sharedURLCache] removeAllCachedResponses];
            });
        }else{
            UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithData:imageData];

            dispatch_sync(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                [self.imgVw setImage:image];
                [self.loadingIndicator stopAnimating];
                [[NSURLCache sharedURLCache] removeAllCachedResponses];
            });
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Also, you will need some mechanism to avoid loading image data every time _cellForRowAtIndexPath_ method calls. First, you try above code. Then we will move forward.

Comment: ok... first thanks @Pratik , but i have still the same problem... but now i know, that he downloads all images correctly, but he release the cell too late. the content has already downloaded, but the cell will released after I scrolled over it. so why does it do this?